# VSCode javascript autocompletition environment

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am developing a website using VSCode as editor, what I notice is that if I write js code inside the HTML the autocomplete shows window and document properties:
[image: window autocompete]

instead on js file the autocomplete does not works:

[image]

maybe I must specify some JSDoc? or configure with jsconfig.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, I added a little jsconfig.json inside the folder with this:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": ["browser"]
    }
}
```